# What is the difference between limit(1) and range(0, 1)?

Tags: 7, database

In a query I tried using `limit(1)`; I got a WSOD, but when I use `range(0,1)` I don't get any WSOD.

What is the basic difference between `limit(1)` and `range(0, 1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base difference is that [`range`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Arange/7) is a method of [`SelectQuery` class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7), and `limit` isn't.

Some APIs can extend SelectQuery and add `limit`. For example  `$query->extendQuery('PagerDefault')` will return object of [`PagerDefault` class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/class/PagerDefault/7) that has [`limit` method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/PagerDefault%3A%3Alimit/7) defined.

It may result in a syntax looking like `limit()` is invoked on `SelectQuery`, when [in fact it isn't](https://drupal.org/node/1060924#comment-6426246):

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n')
      ->condition('type','problem','=')
      ->extend('PagerDefault')
      ->limit(20);
```

Comment: But at the end of the page in the link below limit function is used. https://drupal.org/node/1060924#comment-6426246

Comment: ok. got it , it is usable only for 'pager default'

Comment: Exactly, just what they say there *"looks like it chains with the above, but that's an illusion!"*